# How to position relative to a child element within another control in XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, relativepanel

In a UWP app, I have a custom UserControl with some child controls (text boxes, labels, etc.). I have a Page that includes that UserControl as a child element. Now, I want to place a button below that UserControl and align it with one of the control's child text boxes using a RelativePanel. I can't figure out a way to access the child element.

For example, I have a custom control:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Sandbox.FooControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Sandbox"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <TextBox
        x:Name="TheTextBoxIWantToAlignWith"
        x:FieldModifier="public"/>
</Grid>
```

And now I want to align with "TheTextBoxIWantToAlignWith":

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Sandbox.FooParentControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Sandbox"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<RelativePanel>
    <local:FooControl
        x:Name="Foo"
        RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
        RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>

    <Button
        RelativePanel.Below="Foo"
        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="Foo.TheTextBoxIWantToAlignWith"/> <!-- This doesn't work -->
</RelativePanel>
```

Obviously this doesn't work ("RelativePanel error: The name 'Foo.TheTextBoxIWantToAlignWith' does not exist in the current context."). I tried:

1. Setting the FieldModifier to public on the child TextBox
2. Exposing the TextBox as a public property in code-behind
3. Exposing the TextBox as a DependencyProperty in code-behind

I really want to avoid flattening out the UserControl into the parent page because it can be reused elsewhere. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you create a `DependencyProperty` on the UserControl that is bound to the margin/padding of `TheTextBoxIWantToAlignWith` from the edge of the control, and then bind the Margin/Padding of the `Button` to that?

Comment: Would you tell me the reason for  having this requirement? It seems more complex to use this with binding? And @Lindsay has provided a good workaround that you could refer to.

Comment: I may have over-simplified the example. In the real scenario, there is a label to the left of the text box that has an unknown width (Depending on the text), so margin/padding won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up working around the issue with code-behind, similar to Lindsay's suggestion. I hooked into the LayoutUpdated event, which calculated and set the margin. Something like this:

```
    private void AlignButton()
    {
        var transform = Foo.TheTextBoxIWantToAlignWith.TransformToVisual(RootPanel);
        var textBoxRightEdge = transform .TransformPoint(new Point()).X + Foo.TheTextBoxIWantToAlignWith.ActualWidth;
        var rightMargin = RootPanel.ActualWidth - textBoxRightEdge;

        if (Math.Abs(TheButtonIWantToAlign.Margin.Right - rightMargin) >= 1)
            TheButtonIWantToAlign.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, rightMargin, 0);
    }
```